# Swift Error, it replace the last item only

Tags: ios, swift

I have code that needs to find and delete a string in a textview. The string is saved in an array. The problem is that it deletes from the string only the last item in the array. Instead, I need it to delete all the items in the textview. This is the code :

```
for Value in values! {
    print("ARRAY VALUE= \(Value)")

    newString = reasonView.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\(Value)", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
}
```

How can i resolve that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing always in `reasonView.text` and the result is discarded...

Try this:

```
newString = reasonView.text
for Value in values! {
    print("ARRAY VALUE= \(Value)")

    newString = newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\(Value)", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
}
```

Comment: This seems to work.. but i see it works with words like : hello or hello-how but not with Hello How. So with spaces doesn't work.. Why ?

Comment: anyway i just resolve that, don't worry :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
reasonView.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\(Value)", withString: "")
```